# I am trying to read all lines in a file and if there are duplicates, concatenate them. Here is what I have so far

Tags: java, java-io

```
import java.io.File;
import java.util.List;


public final class ProblemSG3Implementation {
    public final List<String> readEntries(final File psfFile) {
    enter code here
        for (final File fileId : psfFile.listFiles()) {
            if (fileId.isDirectory()) {
                readEntries(fileId);
            } else {
                System.out.println("No files exist");
            }

        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Ovewrflow.  Well, this code doesn't read a file at all from what I see.  Rather, it uses recursion to traverse a directory tree and prints out "No files exist" for each file in the tree.  So you haven't gotten started in actually reading a file.  SO isn't a code writing service.  
 You need to try to get a little closer to a solution.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: so my question is how to I get it to read the files